# Is it possible to run git hook before push and amend the last commit?

Tags: git, githooks, husky

I want to amend the latest commit with the output of some automated script before the push, but for the push to include the latest change. Using [husky](https://www.npmjs.com/package/husky) I've written this:

```
"husky": {
    "hooks": {
        "pre-push": "yarn my-script"
    }
}
```

where

```
"my-script": "custom-script && git add changed.file && git commit --amend --no-edit"
```

The problem with it is that push still works with the commits before the latest amended change - which makes sense to some extent.

Is it possible to do with git-hooks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[pre-push hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_pre_push) can be used to prevent a push but it cannot change commits being pushed. You need one of the [pre-commit hooks](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_pre_commit).